# How can I fix these rendering issues on the Windows 8 Start screen?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I'm seeing some weird symbols on the UI elements on my Start screen. What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're either missing the **Segoe UI Symbol** font, or it's corrupted. You can:

1. Copy it from another PC.
2. [Extract it from the ISO](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-extract-copy-system-files-from-windows-xp-vista-7-or-windows-8-setup/).
3. [Download it](http://media.askvg.com/downloads/2013/01/Install-Segoe-UI-Symbol-Font-in-Windows-8.zip).

<sub>[Source](http://www.askvg.com/fix-unknown-characters-or-vertical-rectangles-are-showing-in-place-of-metro-icons-in-windows-8-start-screen-and-login-screen/)</sub>