# How to revert checkboxes, comboboxes, and scrollbars in Internet Explorer 11 to how they were displayed in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I recently install IE 11 and I wonder that all checkboxes, comboboxes, and scrollbars are changed. Please see these images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How I  can set Internet Explorer 11 to show the classic interface for those elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are some of my user interface symbols rendered as boxes?](http://superuser.com/questions/604186/why-are-some-of-my-user-interface-symbols-rendered-as-boxes)

Answer (score 0):

If this problem occur while rendering 1 website, that could be due to non-compatibility.

You may try to run that url in compatibility mode.

Open Internet Explorer

Press Alt for Menu Bar.

Go to Tools

Select Compatibility View Settings

Add URL and click add, close and try to open URL in IE Now and check if this resolves the problem